# Is it possible to set a post name param dynamically using Robospice + Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, robospice

I'm trying to change name of the post param dynamically.

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/payment/send_rc")
    Abuse setTop(@Field("MrchLogin") String login,
                 @Field("OutSum") int sum,
                 @Field("InvId") int invId,
                 @Field("Desc") String paymentDescription,
                 @Field("shp_payment_no") int adtId,
                 @Field("shp_type") int number,
                 @Field("shp_user") int userID,
                 @Field("shp_month[]") int monthPeriod);
```

This is my method that I'm using and I'm trying to set `monthPeriod` field with dynamic name.
So it can be something like `shp_month[n]` where `n` is my custom integer param name. So is this possible to change name of the post field dynamically?

Comment: Not sure if you can alter the API, but why not use Json Array for that?

Comment: Can you explain your answer or give me a link for example?

Comment: Usually arrays in JSON are represented as `"arrayName": [ any-other-entities-inside-square-bracets ]`, in Retrofit that's equivalent to using `List` as field type (`List<Integer> monthPeriods` in your case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Jake Wharton** said

```
You can use a "@FieldMap Map<String, String>" for that.
```

Looks like Robospice Retrofit module is out of date.